# Is it possible to disable an element's a href but NOT disable all pointer-events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element in a nav menu for which I would like to disable the `a href` link (using CSS ideally, JS if necessary).  The CSS I am currently using to accomplish this is:

`#SideCategoryMenu a { pointer-events: none }`

but that is eliminating *every* CSS event from that link, including `:hover` events and other possible `onclick` events.  How can I alter this code so that *only* the `a` is disabled (or temporarily changed to `href="#"` or something)?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I think, as Styphon notes, you need to detail the problem you're trying to solve with this behaviour, because there's probably a better way to solve it. It *seems* that you want the `<a>` elements to not be click-able, but that begs the question: *why*?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Are you looking to use the `<a>` as a toggle?

Comment: @Styphon - One of my previous questions was marked off-topic because I didn't go into enough detail about the code I already had.  Now I've gone too far?  I'm finding it difficult to word questions in a way that won't be flagged...

Comment: @HenryFloyd You haven't gone too far into your code at all, and you haven't been flagged (although someone did downvote you). The problem is you haven't explained the original problem enough. The first thing that comes to mind when someone see's your question is *why*? If we're asking why you are trying to do what you're doing then you haven't explained the original problem you're trying to solve enough. You should write: The problem I'm trying to solve is X. I have tried Y to solve it but I'm stuck on Z. At the moment you only have Y and Z, you need to include X first. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a case of links being used as buttons....but [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your code:

```
$('#SideCategoryMenu a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will cancel all actions when the link is clicked.